# Border Problems with Responsive Vertical Page Navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs

I need your help with a series of smaller questions which maybe a one-stop fix, who knows. I can't seem to figure this out on my own anymore and require a fresh set of eyes to glance over my HTML and CSS coding. I have also attached screenshots of each of the problems that I am having:

Problem #1:
There seems to be a broken bottom border in my tabs when the active Tab is selected.
[image]

Problem #2:
The top or bottom border appears to be slightly thicker when the active Tab is switched to another Tab.
[image]

Problem #3:
On the last tab, when selected as the active Tab, the bottom border is missing completely?
[image]

Problem #4:
How do I get rid of the 1px border on the right, when any of the the active tab are switched?
[image]

Each border either selected or not should remain 1px only.

Here is the HTML and CSS Code in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: #fff;
            font-family: Segoe UI;
            font-size: 9pt;
            padding-top: 50px;
        }
        #vtab {
            margin: auto;
            width: 800px;
            height: 100%;
        }
        #vtab > ul > li {
            width: 110px;
            height: 110px;

            background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
            list-style-type: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            margin: auto;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            position: relative;

            border-top: 1px solid rgb(214,214,214);
            border-left: 1px solid rgb(214,214,214);
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(214,214,214);

        }
        #vtab > ul > li.home {
            /* background: url('home.png') no-repeat center center; */
        }
        #vtab > ul > li.login {
            /* background: url('login.png') no-repeat center center; */
        }
        #vtab > ul > li.support {
            /* background: url('support.png') no-repeat center center; */
        }
        #vtab > ul > li.selected {
            margin-right: 5px;
            z-index: 10;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #FFF;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
        }
        #vtab > ul {
            float: left;
            width: 110px;
            text-align: left;
            display: block;
            margin: auto 0;
            padding: 0;
            position: relative;
            top: 20px;
        }
        #vtab > div {
            background-color: #fafafa;
            margin-left: 110px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            min-height: 500px;
            padding: 12px;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 9;
        }
        #vtab > div > h4 {
            color: #800;
            border-bottom: 1px dotted #800;
            padding-top: 5px;
            margin-top: 0;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var $items = $('#vtab>ul>li');
            $items.mouseover(function() {
                $items.removeClass('selected');
                $(this).addClass('selected');

                var index = $items.index($(this));
                $('#vtab>div').hide().eq(index).show();
            }).eq(1).mouseover();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="vtab">
        <ul>
            <li class="selected">Tab1</li>
            <li>Tab2</li>
            <li>Tab3</li>
            <li>Tab4</li>
        </ul>

        <div>
            <h4>Tab1 Content</h4>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dictum tincidunt
            metus, vitae porta elit mollis eget. Sed id nisl nec lorem tincidunt sodales. Etiam
            a dolor tellus, vel rhoncus ligula? Duis adipiscing vehicula urna ut pellentesque!
            Duis eleifend lacinia diam a rhoncus. Integer viverra dolor eget eros consequat
            facilisis. Curabitur dignissim dignissim lacinia!
            <br />
            <br />
            Sed bibendum velit et magna placerat bibendum. Donec vitae leo ante. Nulla semper
            dapibus felis et luctus. Donec congue, lectus eget ullamcorper sagittis, orci enim
            aliquam risus, eget adipiscing quam neque sed eros. Donec commodo nisi varius augue
            lacinia pharetra. Cras lacinia fermentum luctus. Nunc venenatis commodo lorem, vitae
            pulvinar neque dignissim sed. Proin blandit rhoncus risus, sit amet eleifend quam
            eleifend sed.
        </div>

        <div>
            <h4>Tab2 Content</h4>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dictum tincidunt
            metus, vitae porta elit mollis eget. Sed id nisl nec lorem tincidunt sodales. Etiam
            a dolor tellus, vel rhoncus ligula? Duis adipiscing vehicula urna ut pellentesque!
            Duis eleifend lacinia diam a rhoncus. Integer viverra dolor eget eros consequat
            facilisis. Curabitur dignissim dignissim lacinia!
            <br/><br/>
            Sed bibendum velit et magna placerat bibendum. Donec vitae leo ante. Nulla semper
            dapibus felis et luctus. Donec congue, lectus eget ullamcorper sagittis, orci enim
            aliquam risus, eget adipiscing quam neque sed eros. Donec commodo nisi varius augue
            lacinia pharetra. Cras lacinia fermentum luctus. Nunc venenatis commodo lorem, vitae
            pulvinar neque dignissim sed. Proin blandit rhoncus risus, sit amet eleifend quam
            eleifend sed.    
        </div>

        <div>
            <h4>Tab3 Content</h4>
            Maecenas in varius nulla. Morbi leo elit, volutpat ac faucibus in; aliquam eget
            massa. Nullam a neque ac turpis luctus venenatis et placerat risus. Quisque pretium
            scelerisque sapien, et accumsan nunc venenatis non. Donec ullamcorper, leo gravida
            hendrerit interdum, tellus nisi vestibulum justo; quis dignissim enim risus quis
            ipsum.<br />
            <br />
            Mauris fringilla, urna vitae posuere commodo, neque tellus tincidunt nisi, aliquam
            scelerisque purus nulla ac enim. Cras urna urna, vestibulum ut aliquam sed, laoreet
            et justo! Vestibulum eleifend porta mollis. Donec molestie, turpis sed commodo consequat,
            erat purus sollicitudin arcu, non vestibulum risus lacus ac ipsum. Curabitur vitae
            pellentesque purus.
        </div>

        <div>
            <h4>Tab4 Content</h4>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum dictum tincidunt
            metus, vitae porta elit mollis eget. Sed id nisl nec lorem tincidunt sodales. Etiam
            a dolor tellus, vel rhoncus ligula? Duis adipiscing vehicula urna ut pellentesque!
            Duis eleifend lacinia diam a rhoncus. Integer viverra dolor eget eros consequat
            facilisis. Curabitur dignissim dignissim lacinia!
            <br />
            <br />
            Sed bibendum velit et magna placerat bibendum. Donec vitae leo ante. Nulla semper
            dapibus felis et luctus. Donec congue, lectus eget ullamcorper sagittis, orci enim
            aliquam risus, eget adipiscing quam neque sed eros. Donec commodo nisi varius augue
            lacinia pharetra. Cras lacinia fermentum luctus. Nunc venenatis commodo lorem, vitae
            pulvinar neque dignissim sed. Proin blandit rhoncus risus, sit amet eleifend quam
            eleifend sed.
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you please add a fiddle

Comment: fiddle is: https://jsfiddle.net/qy9oLzu8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not run into the broken border or side border problems in your fiddle. As for the thick border/invisible border, here is the change you can make:

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qy9oLzu8/1/

```
#vtab > ul > li.selected {
            margin-right: 5px;
            z-index: 10;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #FFF;
            border-bottom: 0px solid #FFF;            
            border-top: 0px solid #FFF;
        }
         #vtab > ul > li:first-child.selected {
            border-top: 1px solid rgb(214,214,214);
        }
         #vtab > ul > li:last-child.selected {
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(214,214,214);
        }
```

Simply bring the top border back on the first child, and the bottom one on the last child. I hope this helps :)